# FrameLayout inside the FrameLayout and positioning FrameLayout right side of the parent FrameLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout

I'm trying create one Framelayout that contains a child Framelayout, I'm not able to position the child Framelayout to the right side of the parent Framelayout!.

I tried with `android:foregroundGravity="right"` and  `android:layout_weight="1"`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_weight="1">    

<com.example.ListViewActivity
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</com.example.ListViewActivity>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/indexRight"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@color/white"      
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Screen Shot: [image]

As mentioned in the above image I want to move the white FrameLayout into right.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) on `FrameLayout`

> FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display
>   a single item

You should use a `LinearLayout` or a `RelativeLayout` as root, unless you want to display only one child at any given time. I assume that `com.example.ListViewActivity` is a custom View you have implemented, and NOT an actual `Activity`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">    

    <com.example.ListViewActivity
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </com.example.ListViewActivity>

    <!-- This FrameLayout will be located on the right side, with the ListView on its left side -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/indexRight"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/white">
        <!-- SINGLE child here -->
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks, 'com.example.ListViewActivity' custom view should contain parent FrameLayout !